# Kie drools wb -Build And Deploy class loading issue after adding external dependency

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, kie

I have created kie project on JBOSS ,and when i am adding external project as dependency,i am getting exception

```
Failed to define class org.dom4j.xpp.ProxyXmlStartTag in Module 
"deployment.kiedrools.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError:     Failed to link org/dom4j/xpp/ProxyXmlStartTag (Module "deployment.kiedrools.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)


Caused by:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.xpp.XmlStartTag from [Module "deployment.kiedrools.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

I have also try by adding pull-parser jar containing XmlStartTag class,but then issue comes for another class.

Comment: All dependencies need to be on the classpath. It sounds like there are just more dependencies that you need to add. The Maven Shade plugin can help in bundling all of those external dependencies into a single jar.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Steve,but i am already using Maven Shade Plugin for making jar.Jboss is providing Dom4j in its module,Kie web distribution also using Dom4j and the external jar i am uploading to Kie project is also using Dom4j,i think issue is coming because of conflict during classloading,but i am not able to get it resolve

Comment: So when you fix this issue it's returning a ClassNotFoundException for a class that can be found in Dom4J?

Comment: Yes steve you are right,same is happening.When i fix issue for one class it's returning a ClassNotFoundException for another class that can be found in Dom4J